# Why is my state not initialized in flutter Consumer/Provider?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

At the bottom of `main`

```
var nums = state.getItems();
print("nums: " + nums.toString());
```

nums is null, maybe I am initializing it wrong? Thank you

## main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => TheState(),
      child: const MyHomePage(
        title: 'ok',
      )));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      var state = Provider.of<TheState>(context, listen: false);
      state.dbInit();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const DogList();
  }
}

class DogList extends StatelessWidget {
  const DogList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TheState>(
      builder: (context, state, child) {
        var nums = state.getItems();
        print("nums: " + nums.toString());
```

## TheState.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TheState extends ChangeNotifier {
  int? items;
  Query? _feedQuery;
  final DatabaseReference kDb = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
  Future<bool> dbInit() {
    try {
      _feedQuery!.onChildAdded.listen(_childAdded);
      //_feedQuery!.onChildChanged.listen(_onTweetChanged);
      initItems();
      return Future.value(true);
    } catch (error) {
      print("ERROR");
      return Future.value(false);
    }
  }

  int? getItems() {
    return items;
  }

  void initItems() {
    var calledFrom = "getItems";
    try {
      print("in try" + " " + calledFrom);
      kDb.child('tweet').once().then((DatabaseEvent event) {
        print("returned" + " " + calledFrom);
        final snapshot = event.snapshot;
        if (snapshot.value != null) {
          var map = snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
          items = map.length;
        }
      }).catchError((e, stackTrace) {
        print("in catchError" + " " + calledFrom);
      }).whenComplete(() => print("COMPLETE" + " " + calledFrom));
    } catch (error) {
      print("catch" + " " + calledFrom);
    } finally {
      print("finally" + " " + calledFrom);
    }
  }

  void _childAdded(DatabaseEvent event) {}
}
```

Comment: How about adding the `notifyListeners()` function after the `items = map.length;` line?

Comment: tried your comment, print("nums: " + nums.toString()); still null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `notifyListeners()` after the you get data

```
void initItems() {
    var calledFrom = "getItems";
    try {
      print("in try" + " " + calledFrom);
      kDb.child('tweet').once().then((DatabaseEvent event) {
        print("returned" + " " + calledFrom);
        final snapshot = event.snapshot;
        if (snapshot.value != null) {
          var map = snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;
          items = map.length;
          notifyListeners();
        }
      }).catchError((e, stackTrace) {
        print("in catchError" + " " + calledFrom);
      }).whenComplete(() => print("COMPLETE" + " " + calledFrom));
    } catch (error) {
      print("catch" + " " + calledFrom);
    } finally {
      print("finally" + " " + calledFrom);
    }
  }
```

Comment: tried your solution, print("nums: " + nums.toString()); still null

Comment: add your `print` method to the above `notifyListeners` and find out you get data correctly

Comment: its null before db returns, but the UI errors on this null value before db returns. After it errors once, UI seems to rebuild widget ok without error, but the screen still shows original red error screen.

Comment: yes because you have no data before that. so, you can simply set by default value or add some loading component